# What is the 'Data Date' in the special fields in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

There are a few special fields in Crystal Reports, like "Print Date" and "File Created Date"

Source: http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/9fbcfa6e-0871-4935-bb28-7ef7417cd233/Special%20Fields%20in%20Crystal%20Report

But what is the "Data Date"? In the link above it says that File Created Date is the date that the report was run. It doesn't mention what Data Date is.

Assuming that Data Date is the date that the database data was accessed, wouldn't that be the same as File Created?

Answer (score 1):

DataDate, According to Crystal reports 2008 complete reference:

> Returns a date value indicating the last date that data on the report was refreshed from
>   the database.
>   DataDate will be the same date that appears to the left of the page navigation controls in
>   the Preview tab. Click Report | Refresh Report Data (or use the appropriate toolbar button
>   or keyboard shortcut) to refresh the database and update this value to the current date.

FileCreationDate, on the other hand:

> Returns a date value indicating the date that the report file was first created.
>   This value will not change if the report is later opened, modified, and resaved.